# Detecting input consisting of just spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a wepage for a user to sign up,i have tested it and runned it,i was testing it using space not entering any words to signup,meaning a user can signup without entering any words just by using space.so i dont want this to happen to my webpage.

any one who has some code that i can use to validate this...

Comment: You can check if the entered value is empty by applying the Trim function.

Comment: @AhmadAl-Mutawa How do i apply the Trim function?

Comment: Please make the title more specific, that way your question will be easier to find for people who want to know the same thing.

Comment: The function String.IsNullOrWhitespace is particularly helpful (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx). You can also use the FieldValidator controls, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx

Comment: @PuseletsoMichelle Why not use a Required Field Validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either the simple `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

or if you really want to use the answer you chose, you should edit it to:

```
if (firstName ! = null && lastName ! = null)
{
    if (firstName.Trim()=="" || lastName.Trim()=="")
    {
        return False;
    }

    else
    {
        return True;
    }
}
else return False;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method: [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) to check

Answer (score 0):

you can validate user input in many ways. One of them is to use built in Visual Studio Vaidator controls and make sure that each control is tighed to a text box in your form and its preoperty is selected to ensure the field is filled before submitting the form.

Another way is to do the validation from the code behind. Something like this:

```
if (firstName.Trim()=="" || lastName.Trim()=="")
{
    return False;
}
else
{
    return True;
}
```

Comment: Maybe prefer `String.Empty` to `""` (easily confusable with `" "` IMO) ?